# Lightbox or Fancybox with Rails 4.1.4 only works after refresh

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I'm trying to use lighbox or fancybox in my application without gems...

I already try put in assets/javascript and assets/stylesheet .js and .css files. But they only works when i refresh the page.

in my application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        });
    </script>
```

output:

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/jquery.fancybox.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/novidades.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/home.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.fancybox.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/novidades.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        });
    </script>
```

Whats is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Turbolniks**

Even though you mentioned you're doing this "without gems", it has all the hallmarks of an issue with `turbolinks`

In case you don't know, Turbolinks is a gem bundled with Rails to help load pages quicker. It does this by essentially pulling the `<body>` content of a page, leaving the `<head>` intact.

Although Turbolinks works very the majority of the time, it has one major flaw - because JS doesn't get refreshed when you load the page (as the `head` area of the page stays the same), JS generally doesn't "work" unless you refresh the page (and consequently refresh the `<head>` tag).

--

**Fix**

There are several ways to "fix" this - basically getting your JS to work with the Turbolinks refresh:

Firstly, you need to use the Turbolinks [Events](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var fancybox = function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
};
$(document).on("page:load ready", fancybox);
```

This *should* work for you. An alternative solution would be to use [Javascript Delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate), although I don't think it would work with Fancybox in this instance

Comment: Thanks for help me, this code didn't work for me, but your explanation help me to understand the real problem, so i tried "$('.fancybox').fancybox({ parent: "body"});" on application.js and works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            parent : 'body'
        });
    });
</script>
```

add {parent : 'body'} work for me!

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me, so i though i'll drop what worked for me, while using turbolinks and fancybox v1:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {

  // this makes sure fancybox has all the elements it needs,
  // that turbolinks removed, while changing page
  $.fancybox.init();

  $('*[data-js-image-popup]').fancybox( {} );

});
```